# How to update or copy data between 2 tables SQL

Tags: sql, toad

I have table name Merge_table  like :

```
 Employee_Number   MINISTRY_CODE   BRANCH_SECRETARIAT_CODE

    12                 333                 30
    13                 222                 31
```

l want to copy the value of `BRANCH_SECRETARIAT_CODE` and paste it in different table  called `EMPLOYMENTS` look like :
and `ENTITY_BRANCH` has null data

```
 EMPLOYEE_NUMBER    JOINING_DATE      ENTITY_BRANCH 

     12              11/12/2006          null
     13              01/11/2009          null
```

so, now i want to copy the value of BRANCH_SECRETARIAT_CODE from table1 to 
table2 ENTITY_BRANCH for each employee according his `EMPLOYEE_NUMBER`

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 2):

You can declare several tables in your UPDATE instruction and specify which column of which table has to be updated from the values of the other table.

In your case you have only 2 tables so the easier is to make an implict jointure using `T1.Employee_Number  = T2.Employee_Number`   :

```
UPDATE Table1 T1, Table2 T2
SET T2.ENTITY_BRANCH  = T1.BRANCH_SECRETARIAT_CODE 
WHERE T1.Employee_Number  = T2.Employee_Number
```

I guessed this is for SQL server but this UPDATE statement will work also on MySQL and Access. Please edit your question to add the proper RDBMS tag.

Comment: I'm sceptical about that being ANSI SQL, so I assume that's not what you actually meant by "this UPDATE statement will work on any RDBMS". Anyway, I prefer using `merge` in cases like this: I know that's ANSI, and it enables using proper `join`s between source and destination (and among multi-table sources).

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Where have your read that it is standard Ansi? I specified that it should work on any RDBMS, but indeed I should have say "most of them" instead. It Works on Oracle, SQL server, Access, MySQL, and many others. Adapting anyway.

Comment: It does not work with "most" DBMS. It does not work with Oracle, Postgres, DB2, Firebird, SAP HANA, HSQLDB, H2, Apache Derby, Informix, Vertica.

Comment: Just tested it with Oracle, it indeed doesnt work. I swore it did!  My appologies :-) Too much DBMS here...

Answer (score 1):

Use the ANSI Standard's [`merge` statement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_(SQL)), which provides better `join`-style syntax for matching source and destination tables, supports complex source clauses, supports `insert`s too, etc.

```
merge into EMPLOYMENTS -- destination table
using Merge_table      -- source table, or nested subquery, CTE, etc.
on Merge_table Employee_Number = EMPLOYMENTS.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER
    -- any other criteria to determine which destination rows to affect
    -- e.g.: and EMPLOYMENTS.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER is null
-- when not matched then
--     [...]
when matched then
    update
    set EMPLOYMENTS.ENTITY_BRANCH = Merge_table.BRANCH_SECRETARIAT_CODE;
```

Comment: l try then i got this error ORA-00969: missing ON keyword

Comment: So edit your question to tag which, presumably non-ANSI-compliant, DBMS you are using. Otherwise people are guessing in the dark - which is pointless. But given that you only tagged `sql`, we're well within our rights to assume you want a hypothetical Standardised solution, regardless of how many DBMSes skimp out on compliance. Yours is presumably ORAcle. I don't know what it's complaining about: there's an `on` right there. Did you run it as-is? Maybe remove the comments. I dunno. Does Oracle's DBMS _really_ not have any better error messages than that? Would a line number be too much to ask?